# (Android)Load an image asynchronous in listview from an URL

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, loadimage, android-query

My boss said I have to use Android Query, and i found this site: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading
But i tried with:

```
  aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

In my code, but i get this error:
"aq cannot be resolved"
What do i have to do to initialize that aq, do i have to import some lib?

This is my list view adapter:
    public static class ListViewAdapterWall extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

```
    public ListViewAdapterWall(Context context) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ListviewContentWall.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListContent holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewinflate, null);

            holder = new ListContent();
            holder.wallImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.wallImage1);
            holder.wallButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.wallButton1);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
        }

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(convertView);

        aq.id(R.id.wallImage1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
        //holder.wallImage.setBackgroundDrawable(ListviewContentWall.get(position));
        //holder.wallButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ListviewContentWall.get(position));
        //holder.text2.setText(ListviewContent2.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: try with ` AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to search on the internet for the lib: android-query-0.22.10.jar and put it in my libs folder for it to work

Answer (score 1):

`AQuery` is a wrapper around a View.

Initialize it as follows

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(imageView);
```

This snippet is from the same page that you mentioned!

Comment: Same think with imageView,context or convertView. That line gets this error:

Multiple markers at this line
 - AQuery cannot be resolved to a type
 - AQuery cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Did you add the library properly then?

Comment: What library do i have to add? Don't they add themselves? or at least he should asc me at the errors to: add import.dontknowname ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Query ImageLoading has recycle() methods.

Javadoc from android_query says, recycle() method as

> public T recycle(View root)
>     Recycle this AQuery object. The method is designed to avoid recreating an AQuery object repeatedly, such as when in list adapter getView method.
>
> Parameters:
>
> root - The new root of the recycled AQuery.
>
> Returns:
>
> self

and here is source adjust above method.

```
AQuery listAq = new AQuery(this);

public ListViewAdapterWall(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return ListviewContentWall.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListContent holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewinflate, null);

        holder = new ListContent();
        holder.wallImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.wallImage1);
        holder.wallButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.wallButton1);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
    }

    AQuery aq = listAq.recycle(convertView);

    aq.id(R.id.wallImage1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
    //holder.wallImage.setBackgroundDrawable(ListviewContentWall.get(position));
    //holder.wallButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ListviewContentWall.get(position));
    //holder.text2.setText(ListviewContent2.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```